# Disable location bar in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, window.open

I'm using `window.open` for a click event in jQuery. 
The problem is that I want to disable the location bar, it works in Safari but not in Chrome.
I heard somewhere that it is impossible to get rid of the location bar in Chrome, is this true?

**Here's the code:**

```
var features = "left=200,toolbar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,menubar=0,status=0,width=510,height=547";
window.open(URL, NAME, features);
```

Comment: As you probably know, there are the well known location=no, addressbar=no etc, but not all browsers follow this. Some of this is because of security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get rid of it in chrome, but `location=0` will make it so that it can't be edited at least.  It will still appear, but they can't change the location.  Past that, there's nothing you can do, though.